# How to check/repair bad sectors on a U22.10?

Tags: filesystem, data-corruption

Let's say I'm having what appear to be inode corruptions (actual problem: switching to read-only) requiring reboot then fsck repair. I've done that and my system (U22.10 desktop) is "healthy" again. But then a few days later it happens again. I repeat the fsck repair and again I'm "healthy" and back in my system. How can I do a check for (and repair?) bad disk sectors on my running live system? The standard gui-app Disks doesn't allow that. I'm guessing that's not really possible, so what products (HDD Regenerator-like) for my U22.10 would help with check and repair? I'm on a Lenovo T13 Gen1 with an SSD .5 tb with 200 gb free, U22.10 only, no dual-boot.

Comment: There is no repair the drive is dying. Also you can not do any kind of hardware disk repair on a running system.

Comment: Use to restore GNOME Disks on Live USB stick: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview  Hard Disk Sentinel Linux Edition (FREE): https://www.hdsentinel.com/hard_disk_sentinel_linux.php  Solid state drive: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Solid_state_drive

Comment: @JohanPalych: An HDSentinel run says `...Health  : 98 % Performance  : 100 % The status of the solid state disk is PERFECT. Problematic or weak sectors were not found.` Could something I'm running be attacking my file system?